# How can I render a view as JSON inside a template file?

Tags: 8, views

I would like to render a view as JSON, within the page template. I would hide it with CSS and use it with JavaScript.

Is there a way to alter the *Format* field used when creating a view, which normally shows options like *Grid*, *HTML List*?

I did try the *Rest Export* core module, but it seems to render the view as JSON with no other page content.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127163/discussion-on-question-by-hayden-thring-how-can-i-render-a-view-as-json-inside-a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though originally I wanted to avoid making subsequent requests to the server, it seems its the easiest way to get around this. Just make some views that output json and load them with ajax.